# Python: selenium webdriver click button execution problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written a code to perform button clicking using 'selenium webdriver'.

```
# importing webdriver from selenium
from selenium import webdriver

# Here Chrome  will be used
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# URL of website
url = "anyurl"

# Opening the website
driver.get(url)

# geeting the button by class name
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("specified_button")

# clicking on the button
button.click()
```

After installing the selenium pakage(using pip), I did run this code with absolutely valid url. But,
it throws errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Self AI/clickonsite.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

If someone help me fix this problem, I'd be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location of the Chrome driver.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"pathOfYourChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")
```

driver can be download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.

Anyway you must add `time.sleep()` because you must give the site time to load.

And it's better to use xpath, id, name, css selector than class name.

Comment: Is the driver connected to the chrome browser?? I mean, if I have logged in to the google accounts in the chrome browser, will it be accessible by the driver??

Comment: No, the chrome driver is not connected to your cookies and password on the regular google chrome. It will no open the chrome with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "webdriver_manager". By using this, you will not have to update your browser driver whenever the new versions are released for browsers. This is going to work for all the browsers.

Just two simple steps Installing the "webdriver_manager".Execute this on command prompt.

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

Then in the code,for Chrome :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

For Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

For Edge:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
```